# Using multiple number formats with names styles in openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm using openpyxl to generate Excel files. I start by opening an existing workbook with some predefined styles such as 'MyHeading1', and then setting a cell equal to this style like so:

```
ws['D5'].style = 'MyHeading1'
```

That works, but what I'm struggling with is setting the correct number format. Some of the cells are numbers while others are dates. I've tried the following without success.

```
if isinstance(value, datetime.date):
    cell.number_format = 'dd-mmm-yy'
else:
    cell.number_format = '# ##0.00'
```

So my question is what is the correct way to deal with multiple number formats where the other formatting of the cell is the same?

Answer (score 2):

there is a default value for style such as fond is 'Calibri' and size is 11. You may refer to this[1](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/styles.html) to get more detail information. The reason you cannot assign cell.number_format may be that you assign the cell as general form then use `isinstance(value, datetime.date)` which is not date format anymore. You may check `ws['D5'].number_format` to verify it. The following code may help you:

```
wb = Workbook()
ws1 = wb.create_sheet(title="example")
ws1['D5'].value = datetime.datetime.strptime('24052010', '%d%m%Y').date()
if isinstance(ws1['D5'].value, datetime.date):
    ws1['D5'].number_format = 'dd-mmm-yy'
else:
    ws1['D5'].number_format = '# ##0.00'
wb.save(filename = 'test.xlsx')
```

Comment: The issue is once I set the style using ws['D5'].style = 'MyHeading1' then I can't change the number format. Whenever I change the number format like  you have above then it changes it for all cells with that style.

Comment: Could you attach more your code? Maybe I can try to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The named style has a number format, once that named style is assigned, it can't be changed:

> NB. once you have assigned a named style to a cell, additional changes
>   to the style will not affect the cell.

https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html#named-styles